# order of the splitting field of $x^5 +x^4 +1 $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

what  is the order of the splitting field of

$x^5 +x^4 +1  = (x^2 +x +1)( x^3 +x+1)$  over $\mathbb{Z_2}$

i thinks  it will  $6$ because  $2.3 = 6$

Pliz help  me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x^5 +x^4 +1  = (x^2 +x +1)( x^3 +x+1)$ and the factors are irreducible, the splitting field of $x^5 +x^4 +1$ has degree at least $2 \cdot 3 = 6$.

On the other hand, the splitting field of $x^5 +x^4 +1$ is contained in $\mathbb F_{2^6}$, an extension of degree $6$. Hence this is the splitting field. Indeed, [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E%7B2%5E6%7D-x+mod+2) tells us that 
$$
x^{2^6}-x = x (x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1) (x^3 + x + 1) \cdots
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is everything ok. This is an answer, not a comment, in order to insert the following confirmation using computer assistance, here [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: F = GF(2)
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(F)
sage: f = x^5+x^4+1
sage: f.factor()
(x^2 + x + 1) * (x^3 + x + 1)
sage: K.<a> = f.splitting_field()
sage: K
Finite Field in a of size 2^6
sage:  a.minpoly()
x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1
sage: f.base_extend(K).factor()
(x + a^3 + a^2 + a)
    * (x + a^3 + a^2 + a + 1)
    * (x + a^4 + a^2 + a + 1)
    * (x + a^5 + a)
    * (x + a^5 + a^4 + a^2 + 1)
```

The code was minimally rearranged for the last result to fit in the window.

For the first polynomial in the factorization $(x^2 + x + 1) (x^3 + x + 1)$ we need an extension from $\Bbb F_2$ to $\Bbb F_{2^2}$, then from this one a new degree three extension to $\Bbb F_{(2^2)^3}$ to split also the second factor $x^3+x+1$.

Comment: can  u edit   ur answer  as im not getting...write in proper maths jax

Comment: In my browser the text is displayed so that i can read it. Which part of it makes problems?